# What is the difference between globalSetup, setupFiles, setupFilesAfterEnv and beforeAll in Jest and what is their specific purpose?

Tags: jestjs

I already read up in the Jest docs and I think they run in this order. Also I understood that globalSetup runs in a different process and thus doesn't share any scope with the regular test suite but with globalTeardown, so this would be a good place to start up a testing database server for example.

Anyhow it's not getting clear to me if I got that right and what I should use the other ones for.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### `globalSetup`

Path to a module that exports an `async` function that will run once before everything.  Globals defined here can only be read in `globalTeardown`.

Typically it makes more sense to mock out any dependencies, but if you have no other choice than to spin up a database or other external service that absolutely must be running during the tests, `globalSetup` would be the place to do it.

---

### `setupFiles` / `setupFilesAfterEnv`

`setupFiles` is a list of modules that will be run once before each test file and before the testing framework is installed.

`setupFilesAfterEnv` is a list of modules that will be run once before each test file but after the testing framework is installed in the environment.

Usually `setupFilesAfterEnv` is the right place for any setup code that should run before each test file.  Only use `setupFiles` if you have a specific reason for needing the code to run *before* the testing framework is installed.

You can think of `setupFilesAfterEnv` as a global `beforeAll`.

If something must be done at the beginning of every test file (for example: [configuring the Enzyme adapter](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/installation/)), it makes sense to do it once in a `setupFilesAfterEnv` file.

---

### `beforeAll`

`Jest` will run all `beforeAll` functions in a test file once before running anything else.

Use `beforeAll` for code that must run once at the beginning of one specific test file.

---

### Example

package.json

```
{

  ...

  "jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./globalSetup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "./globalTeardown.js",
    "setupFiles": ["./setupFile.js"],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./setupFileAfterEnv.js"]
  }
}
```

globalSetup.js

```js
module.exports = async () => {
  console.log('in globalSetup');
  global.GLOBALSETUP = 'globalSetup';
};
```

globalTeardown.js

```js
module.exports = async () => {
  console.log('in globalTeardown');
  console.log(global.GLOBALSETUP);
};
```

setupFile.js

```js
console.log('in setupFile');
global.order = [];
global.order.push(1);
```

setupFileAfterEnv.js

```js
console.log('in setupFileAfterEnv');
global.order.push(2);
```

test.js

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  console.log('in beforeAll');
  global.order.push(3);
});

test('order', () => {
  expect(global.GLOBALSETUP).toBeUndefined();  // SUCCESS
  expect(global.order).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);  // SUCCESS
});
```

Output

```
Determining test suites to run...in globalSetup
  console.log
    in setupFile

      at Object.<anonymous> (setupFile.js:1:98)

  console.log
    in setupFileAfterEnv

      at Object.<anonymous> (setupFileAfterEnv.js:1:1)

  console.log
    in beforeAll

      at Object.<anonymous>.beforeAll (src/test.js:3:11)

 PASS  src/test.js
  ✓ order (4 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.658 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
in globalTeardown
globalSetup

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Comment: Great answer. Well laid out with examples and excellent formatting. Well done and thanks!